# Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection() function not working when compiled for 64-bit in Visual Studio in Window 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am facing an issue with `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()`.

When I compile for a 64-bit platform in Visual Studio 2010, it is not working in Window 10, it returns with error 1.

But, when I compile for a 32-bit platform instead, the function works in Window 10.

```
typedef BOOL(__stdcall *tFSRED)(HMODULE );

HMODULE hKernel = LoadLibrary(_T("Kernel32.dll")); // Get Kernel module handle
if (hKernel == NULL)
{
    return 2;
}

tFSRED pFunc;
pFunc = (tFSRED) GetProcAddress(hKernel, "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection");
ret = pFunc(&oldValue);  // Turn the file the file system redirector off
if (ret == FALSE)
{
    _tprintf(_T("\nFile System Redirection could not be turned off. Reason: %d"), GetLastError());
    return 4;
}
// ret is always TRUE when compile through 32-bit platform
// but ret return FALSE when compile through 64-bit platform
```

In Visual Studio, if I compile for 64-bit platform, then after compile if I open the generated EXE in `depends.exe`, it shows 64 in front of the EXE.

After selecting a 32-bit platform, the generated EXE is 32-bit. That EXE works in my case, but I want my EXE to be 64-bit, so I am selecting 64-bit platform and I get a 64-bit EXE, but it is not working as I explained above.

Comment: Include the code in the question body so you can format it properly as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOW64 emulation only applies to 32-bit executables running on a 64-bit system.  A 64-bit EXE **should not** try to use WOW64 functions (other than maybe `IsWow64Process()`) because the EXE will not be running inside of WOW64 to begin with.  That is why you are getting error code 1 (`ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`) in your 64-bit EXE.

So, either:

- ifdef the code to skip WOW64 functions in a 64-bit compilation:

  ```
  #ifndef _WIN64
  typedef BOOL (WINAPI *tFSDisable)(PVOID*);
  typedef BOOL (WINAPI *tFSRevert(PVOID);

  HMODULE hKernel = GetModuleHandle(_T("Kernel32"));
  tFSDisable pDisableFunc = (tFSDisable) GetProcAddress(hKernel, "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection");
  tFSRevert pRevertFunc = (tFSRevert) GetProcAddress(hKernel, "Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection");

  PVOID oldValue;

  if ((pDisableFunc) && (pRevertFunc))
  {
      if (!pDisableFunc(&oldValue))  // Turn off the file system redirector
      {
          _tprintf(_T("\nFile System Redirection could not be turned off. Reason: %d"), GetLastError());
          return 4;
      }
  }
  #endif

  // do file system operations as needed...

  #ifndef _WIN64
  if ((pDisableFunc) && (pRevertFunc))
  {
      if (!pRevertFunc(oldValue))  // Restore the file system redirector
      {
          _tprintf(_T("\nFile System Redirection could not be restored. Reason: %d"), GetLastError());
          return 5;
      }
  }
  #endif
  ```
- omit the ifdef and just call the WOW64 functions only if `IsWow64Process()` reports the current process is actually running inside of WOW64:

  ```
  typedef BOOL (WINAPI tW64P)(HANDLE, PBOOL);
  typedef BOOL (WINAPI *tFSDisable)(PVOID*);
  typedef BOOL (WINAPI *tFSRevert(PVOID);

  HMODULE hKernel = GetModuleHandle(_T("Kernel32"));

  tW64P pIsWow64Func = (tW64P) GetProcAddress(hKernel, "IsWow64Process");
  tFSDisable pDisableFunc = NULL;
  tFSRevert pRevertFunc = NULL;

  BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;
  if (pIsWow64Func)
  {
      pIsWow64Func(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64);
      if (bIsWow64)
      {
          pDisableFunc = (tFSDisable) GetProcAddress(hKernel, "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection");
          pRevertFunc = (tFSRevert) GetProcAddress(hKernel, "Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection");
      }
  }

  PVOID oldValue;

  if ((pDisableFunc) && (pRevertFunc))
  {
      if (!pDisableFunc(&oldValue))  // Turn off the file system redirector
      {
          _tprintf(_T("\nFile System Redirection could not be turned off. Reason: %d"), GetLastError());
          return 4;
      }
  }

  // do file system operations as needed...

  if ((pDisableFunc) && (pRevertFunc))
  {
      if (!pRevertFunc(oldValue))  // Restore the file system redirector
      {
          _tprintf(_T("\nFile System Redirection could not be restored. Reason: %d"), GetLastError());
          return 5;
      }
  }
  ```